# Dynamics Ax 2012 Missing Category Column in EcoResProductCategory

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

We are having an issue with the form EcoResProductCategory. At one point, this form had a column named 'Category' that our company utilized.  Somehow this column has gone missing.  My team develops on the CUS level and there is a vendor that I believe pushes additions to the level lower.  As of now, there is no CUS level customization to this form.  When looking at the form in the AOT, it appears that the Category field is in fact present (and visible in the properties).  But once the form is opened, it still doesn't show.

Any ideas or pointers?  I am still new to Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 and I apologize for asking a question like this.

Another Note:  When compared to the AX Demo, it seems like our environment is missing the following label...

[image: Missing Field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, a related data table had a field removed.  Therefore the dropdown was never being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it missing for all users, or for one user? In the latter, it could be that it is hidden by by MorphX (Right-clicked and hidden).

Just to make sure it isn't usage data, delete the usage data for that user.

Comment: I just did a compare to the AX Demo and found a missing field on the form.  I added the picture of the missing location but I'm still in the dark about how to correct it